# Adding icon + container data in a table cell

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a problem with filling a table the way I want and I would hope to get some help.

You see, I have a table which has a set of columns that get its content from a container who in its turn get its from a database.
The thing is, in two of the table columns I would like to have a specific icon added in front of the cell content depending on what the content is.

Now, my problem is I know how to add database content to the table using

`imsiTable.setContainerDataSource(imsiContainer)`

and I know how to add a column of icons using

`imsiTable.addGeneratedColumn("networkStatus", new IconAndLabelCell());`

However, I have no idea of how to combine the two into one column... Needless to say I'm still learning the framework. So if YOU know if there is any good approach of how to iterate the content of an existing column in a table and add an icon after the table is created, I would be extremely grateful..

I will provide more information if needed, please don't hesitate to ask!

Edit:
After continuous requests of the code, here it is:

```
private void createImsiTable() {

    String imsiColumn = I18N.get("inventory.imsi.table.imsi");
    String networkStatusColumn = I18N
            .get("inventory.imsi.table.networkstatus");
    String subscriptionStatusColumn = I18N
            .get("inventory.imsi.table.subscriptionstatus");
    String activeImsiColumn = I18N.get("inventory.imsi.table.activeimsi");
    String networkProvisioningColumn = I18N
            .get("inventory.imsi.table.networkprovisioning");
    String simProvisioningColumn = I18N
            .get("inventory.imsi.table.simprovisioning");

    List<Object> visibleColumnIds = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<String> visibleColumnLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

    visibleColumnIds.add("imsi");
    visibleColumnIds.add("networkStatus");
    visibleColumnIds.add("subscriptionStatus");
    visibleColumnIds.add("activeImsi");
    visibleColumnIds.add("networkProvisioning");
    visibleColumnIds.add("simProvisioning");

    visibleColumnLabels.add(imsiColumn);
    visibleColumnLabels.add(networkStatusColumn);
    visibleColumnLabels.add(subscriptionStatusColumn);
    visibleColumnLabels.add(activeImsiColumn);
    visibleColumnLabels.add(networkProvisioningColumn);
    visibleColumnLabels.add(simProvisioningColumn);

    imsiTable.setPageLength(5);
    imsiTable.setCacheRate(1.2);

    /**
     * Keep an eye on batch and cache size preferences to see if they are
     * correctly set for the context
     */
    AbstractQuery imsiQuery = new ImsiQuery(inventoryService, 100, 200);
    this.imsiContainer = new ImsiContainer(imsiQuery);

    imsiContainer.addContainerProperty("id", Long.class, "", true, true);
    imsiContainer.addContainerProperty("imsi", Long.class, "", true, true);
    imsiContainer.addContainerProperty("networkStatus", String.class, "",
            true, true);
    imsiTable.setContainerDataSource(imsiContainer);

            //This is where one of the column with icon and label are created
    imsiTable.addGeneratedColumn("networkStatus", new IconAndLabelCell(
            "network"));
    imsiTable.addGeneratedColumn("subscriptionStatus",
            new IconAndLabelCell("subscription"));

    imsiTable.addGeneratedColumn("activeImsi",
            new RadiobuttonColumnGenerator());

    imsiContainer.addContainerProperty("networkProvisioning", String.class,
            "", true, true);
    imsiContainer.addContainerProperty("simProvisioning", String.class, "",
            true, true);

    imsiTable.setVisibleColumns(visibleColumnIds.toArray());

    imsiTable.setColumnHeaders(visibleColumnLabels
            .toArray(new String[visibleColumnLabels.size()]));
    imsiTable.setImmediate(true);
    imsiTable.setEditable(false);
    imsiTable.setSelectable(false);
    imsiTable.setWriteThrough(true);

    imsiTable.setWidth("95%");

    imsiTable.setStyleName("v-table-striped");
    setStyleName("inventory-switchsububscription-panel");

    addComponent(imsiTable);
    setComponentAlignment(imsiTable, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
}
```

---

```
    //Class declared inside the the same class as the method createImsiTable()
    class IconAndLabelCell implements Table.ColumnGenerator {

    String propertyType;
    m2mExtendedIconLabel iconLabel;

    public IconAndLabelCell(String propertyType) {
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
    }

    @Override
    public Component generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId,
            final Object columnId) {
        Item item = source.getItem(itemId);

        Property idProperty = item.getItemProperty("id");

        if (propertyType.equals("network")) {
            Property networkStatProperty = item
                    .getItemProperty("networkStatus");
            String networkValue = (String) networkStatProperty.getValue();

            iconLabel = getNetworkTableCell(networkValue);

        } else if (propertyType.equals("subscription")) {
            Property subscriptionStatProperty = item
                    .getItemProperty("subscriptionStatus");
            String subscriptionValue = (String) subscriptionStatProperty
                    .getValue();

            iconLabel = getSubscriptionTableCell(subscriptionValue);

        }

        return iconLabel;
    }
```

---

```
    public class M2mExtendedIconLabel extends HorizontalLayout {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6042368314173011721L;

    private final SLabel label;

    public M2mExtendedIconLabel(final String text, final Style labelStyle, final String iconStyle, final ResourceId resourceId)      {

        final Embedded icon = new Embedded(null, new ThemeResource(resourceId.getId()));

        label = new SLabel();
        label.setValue(text);
        label.setStyleName(Styles.ICON_PREFIX.getStyleName() + labelStyle.getStyleName());
        label.getStyleName();
        System.out.println("CSS Class: " + label.getStyleName());

        icon.setStyleName(iconStyle);

        addComponent(icon);
        addComponent(label);
        setComponentAlignment(label, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);
        setExpandRatio(label, 1.0f);

    }

    /**
     * Sets the description to the HorizontalLayout containing the label and icon.
     * @param description The tooltip text
     */
    @Override
    public void setDescription(final String description) {
        setDescription(description);
    }

    public SLabel getTextLabel() {
        return label;
    }

}
```

---

```
private m2mExtendedIconLabel getNetworkTableCell(String networkValue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    m2mExtendedIconLabel iconLabel = null;

    if (networkValue.equals("Activated")) {

        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Activated", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_active_imsi.png"));
    } else if (networkValue.equals("Activation Ready")) {
        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Inventory", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_inventory_imsi.png"));

    } else if (networkValue.equals("Uninitialized")) {
        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Inventory", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_inventory_imsi.png"));

    } else if (networkValue.equals("Inventory")) {
        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Inventory", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_inventory_imsi.png"));

    } else if (networkValue.equals("Suspended")) {
        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Inventory", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_inventory_imsi.png"));

    } else if (networkValue.equals("Network Deactivated")) {
        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Inventory", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_inventory_imsi.png"));

    } else if (networkValue.equals("Terminated")) {
        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Inventory", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_inventory_imsi.png"));

    } else if (networkValue.equals("Test Ready")) {
        iconLabel = new m2mExtendedIconLabel("Test Ready", Styles.TEXT,
                "m2m-inventory-imsitable-status-icon", new ResourceId(
                        "../m2m/img/table_testready_imsi.png"));

        }

        return iconLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know somethng about Vaadin, are you can/be able put Icon & Text into Vaadin's Label  ???

Comment: I didn't really get the question.. If you're asking if the method IconAndLabelCell() works for adding a label and an icon into the same cell then yes. the problem is that in this case the label will just contain "some text" and not the value from the database. Plus I want the type of icon to be selected depending on the post content in the database.

Comment: :-) hmmm, but I think that's basic for Table, look at their forum or documentations or BugParade

Comment: comment by rickthomas: "Can you post the portion of code related to the binding of the table ?

We did the same thing here, and it's work perfectly..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this sample application that I wrote pretty quickly. The originalContainer is just for demonstrating purposes and represents your actual container. This code assumes that you already have a container (originalContainer) created with simple property types (ie. no Vaadin components).

Even a better solution would be to create the original container with imgtext property type set as Label, so it would never be String in the container and you wouldn't have to make any conversions from String to Label.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void init() {
    Window mainWindow = new Window("MyApplication");

    // Create the original container
    IndexedContainer originalContainer = new IndexedContainer();
    originalContainer.addContainerProperty("id", Integer.class, null);
    originalContainer.addContainerProperty("imgtext", String.class, null);

    // Add some dummy data
    Item item0 = originalContainer.getItem(originalContainer.addItem());
    item0.getItemProperty("id").setValue(1);
    item0.getItemProperty("imgtext").setValue("First");
    Item item1 = originalContainer.getItem(originalContainer.addItem());
    item1.getItemProperty("id").setValue(2);
    item1.getItemProperty("imgtext").setValue("Second");

    // Create a modified container
    IndexedContainer modifiedContainer = new IndexedContainer();
    for(Object propId : originalContainer.getContainerPropertyIds()) {
        if(propId.equals("imgtext")) {
            // Change the imgtext property type from String to Label
            modifiedContainer.addContainerProperty(propId, Label.class, null);
        } else {
            modifiedContainer.addContainerProperty(propId, originalContainer.getType(propId), null);
        }
    }

    // Add the data
    for(Object itemId : originalContainer.getItemIds()) {
        Item item = originalContainer.getItem(itemId);
        Item newItem = modifiedContainer.addItem(itemId);
        for(Object propId : originalContainer.getContainerPropertyIds()) {
            if(propId.equals("imgtext")) {
                String text = item.getItemProperty(propId).getValue().toString();
                Label label = new Label();
                label.setContentMode(Label.CONTENT_XHTML);
                label.setValue("<img src=\"" + getImgUrl(text) + "\" /> " + text);
                newItem.getItemProperty(propId).setValue(label);
            } else {
                newItem.getItemProperty(propId).setValue(item.getItemProperty(propId).getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    // Create the table and set the data source
    Table table = new Table();
    table.setWidth(700, Table.UNITS_PIXELS);
    table.setContainerDataSource(modifiedContainer);

    mainWindow.addComponent(table);
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}

private String getImgUrl(String text) {
    return "http://myurl.com/image.png";
}
}
```

You can have other components in your table as well. See the section "Componets Inside a Table" from [here](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html).

Comment: Thank you for a very informative answer! You got me thinking on the right track with your answer. And even though the version I finally developed differed somewhat from what you proposed this still helped a lot! =)